# Changing particular cells of a Matrix iteratively in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Suppose that we have a (4,4) matrix. My goal is to change iteratively that cells (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(1,2),(2,2),(1,3)

I wrote the following

```
for(i in 1:3){
 for(j in 1:3){
   if(i>j){
  A[i,j] = A[i,j] + sample(c(-1,1),prob=c(0.5,0.5))
}
}
```

However, it doesn't change the correct cells and misses cells that have to be changed.

The matrix A can be of the form

`A = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0),4,4,byrow=T)`

I think that the following chunk of code might be the solution, at least it gives the correct answer for a few runs that I did.

```
A = matrix(c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),4,4,byrow=T)

k = 0 
for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:(3-k)){
    A[i,j] = A[i,j] + sample(c(-1,1),prob=c(0.5,0.5), size = 1)
  }
  k = k + 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you show the expected output.  From the description, I assume you want to change the elements in `(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(1,2),(2,2),(1,3)` by adding `sample`?

Comment: In your code, did you meant `if(i >= j)`

Comment: @akrun Yes, there is no particular output, just to create an algorithm that iteratively changes the cells that I pointed out. My problem is that the matrix is not in a convenient form. In the diagonal we should change only the cells ```(1,1)``` and ```(2,2)```.

Comment: Can you check the changed `for` loop solution in my post.

Comment: @akrun  That one changes also the cells ```(3,2)``` and ```(3,4)``` which shouldn't happen

Comment: @akrun is there a way to define the cells that we want to change and iteratively choose those cells?? For example something like ```for(i in index){ A[i[1],i[2]] = change } ```

Comment: The `i > j` includes `(2, 1)`, (3, 1), and (4, 1) along with `(3, 2)`, (4, 2)` etc.  May be you can change the condition

Comment: @akrun I think I have to totally remove that condition ```i>j``` . I was looking for a command like the ```enumerate``` in Python.

Comment: May be you meant `ind <- as.matrix(subset(expand.grid(1:3, 1:3), Var1 <= Var2))` and then do the assignment

Comment: @akrun I think, I solved it, should I edit the solution in my question?? It would be really helpful if you could check it.

Comment: I created couple of indexes.  I think this one `n <- 3;
j1 <- rep(seq_len(n), rev(seq_len(n)));
i1 <- ave(j1, j1, FUN = seq_along);
ind <- cbind(i1, j1)` reflects correctly the one you wanted

Comment: Sure, you edit the solution

Answer (score 2):

I think you simple forgot to set the `size=` parameter of `sample` to get one draw of the Rademacher universe.

```
set.seed(42)
for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    if (i > j) {
      A[i, j] <- A[i, j] + sample(c(-1, 1), size=1, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
    }
  }
}
A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    0    1    1    0
# [3,]    0    2    0    0
# [4,]    1    0    0    0
```

Another idea is to use a permutation matrix, which you may subset to your needs, and over which you may loop.

```
id <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(ncol(B) - 1, ncol(B) - 2, repetition=T)
(id <- id[c(1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 3), ])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    2    1
# [3,]    3    1
# [4,]    1    2
# [5,]    2    2
# [6,]    1    3

set.seed(42)
for (i in 1:nrow(id)) {
  A[id[i, 1], id[i, 2]] <- A[id[i, 1], id[i, 2]] + 
    sample(c(-1, 1), size=1, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
}
A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    0    1    0
# [3,]    2    1    0    0
# [4,]    1    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a row/column index (`vectorized` approach) by `cbind`ing the vector of index.  Use the index to subset the cells of the matrix and assign (`<-`) after adding the `sample` output to those elements

```
n <- 3
j1 <- rep(seq_len(n), rev(seq_len(n)))
i1 <- ave(j1, j1, FUN = seq_along)
ind <- cbind(i1, j1)
ind
#     i1 j1
#[1,]  1  1
#[2,]  2  1
#[3,]  3  1
#[4,]  1  2
#[5,]  2  2
#[6,]  1  3


A[ind] <- A[ind] + sample(c(-1,1),prob=c(0.5,0.5), 
         size = nrow(ind), replace= TRUE)
```

Comment: Can I do that iteratively, for example, change the (1,1) do an M-H algorithm, then change (2,1) do an M-H algorithm etc. ?

Comment: @Jonathan1234 You meant different functions to be applied for different sets.  In that case you can have different sets of `ind` i.e. `ind1 <- cbind(1:3, 1)` and `ind2 <- cbind(c(1, 2, 1), c(2, 2, 3))`